# What is equivalent code for window.location in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I am currently using window.location for client-side redirection in jQuery. Is there any equivalent syntax to do client-side redirection?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. So you can use `window.location` as well.

Answer (score 9):

You still can do that. JQuery is built upon JavaScript and the DOM.

Answer (score 8):

If you're going to use jQuery, you should appreciate that all it is is **a library that makes some JavaScript tasks easier**. Don't try and use it for every JavaScript task under the sun.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` is provided by the browser's DOM, not jQuery. So if jQuery is not present, it matters not one bit.

Answer (score 0):

window.location is working fine for IE, Firefox and Chrome.